# General linear hypothesis testing in repeated-measures multivariate linear model

Tags: multivariate-regression, f-test, univariate

In a multivariate linear model

$Y = XB + U$,

where within-subject (or repeated-measures) factors are coded as simultaneous response variables in $Y$, a general linear hypothesis can be formulated as

$H_0: L B M = 0$,

where $L$ specifies the contrasts among the levels of a between-subjects variable while $M$ codes the contrasts among the levels of a within-subject factor, $B$ and $U$ ares the regression coefficient and residual matrices respectively.

The traditional univariate testing (e.g., ANOVA) for an effect associated with a within-subject factor can be computed through the sum of squares and cross products (SSP) for the above hypothesis ($H$) and for the errors ($E$), assuming sphericity. From the references I have access to (e.g., SAS documentation), it seems that the computations are done through an orthogonalization process of $M$, and then each $F$-statistic is calculated as $trace(H)/trace(E)$. Unfortunately all the references I've read so far only provide some basic descriptions without any formulas. Thus I have two questions:

1) Is there a formula in which the $F$-statistic of the trace ratio can be expressed directly in terms of the $M$ matrix without the orthogonalization? I vaguely remember seeing somewhere a formula like

$F = trace[H (M' M)^{-1}] / trace[E (M' M)^{-1}]$,

but I can't recall the literature. Could someone provide a reference for the formula?

2) If there is no such explicit formula, how is the orthogonalization exactly done in SAS/SPSS?